# VFH/VFH+ Axis Orientation & Sensor Angles

Tags: navigation

I have been struggling with trying to get the VFH+ implementation working correctly using Orca-Robotics implementation which seems to be the same implementation used in the ROS package and MATLAB and others. I would like to check on a couple of things:

1. Axis orientation for the rover, certainty grid and sensor
   measurement directions?
2. Can I just use a 180 deg sweep of the sonar sensor or do I really need 360 degs?  If I just need 180 deg what do I do with initializaling the grid behind the

To start this is what I think the papers I have read are telling me - but I am usually incorrect:
[image: axis and sensor angle orientation]

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.